# Is there a way to exclude my Android proxy app from the Data Usage screen?

Tags: android, sockets, proxy, nio

I have a system app that sets a forwarding proxy inside android devices. The problem is that since all traffic is redirected to that app, the Data usage screen under settings shows as if all traffic is coming from my app and not other apps.

Reading this: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/index.html helped me understand that you cannot exclude an app from the data usage unless it is built with the system image. (However, VPNService is able to exclude itself from data usage, so if I could find a hack to do this, it would work for me).

When looking at the android system file /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/ctrl it clearly shows that all socket connections are being tagged with my app's uid.

I looked at qtaguid.c (https://github.com/cgjones/android-system-core/blob/master/libcutils/qtaguid.c) and tried to implement the same mechanism but the problem is that I can't even get the file descriptor from my socketChannel. Since android uses SocketChannelImpl, I tried to use reflection to get the fd, but this did not work:

```
clientChannel = server.accept();
Class<?> clientChannelImpl = Class.forName("java.nio.SocketChannelImpl");
Method method = clientChannelImpl.getDeclaredMethod("getFD", new Class<?>[0]);
FileDescriptor fd = (FileDescriptor) method.invoke(clientChannel, null);
Class fileDescriptorClass = FileDescriptor.class;
Field field = fileDescriptorClass.getDeclaredField("fd");
field.setAccessible(true);
```

I guess even if this worked, I have no idea how the TAG is generated so that I can switch it out with every connection. I know the last 4 bytes of this tag is the uid of the app creating the socket in hex, but thats about it.

Is any of this even possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's too late, but anyway.

You should tag client socket, the one you use to establish a remote connection, and not a server socket.